# How to access JSON element which has "-" character in the name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object which returns following values.

```
{
   "articles":[
      {
         "paper-id":"id",
         "paper-id-type":"type",
         "title":"title",
         "url":"url",
         "abstract":"abs",
         "date":"date",
         "publication-forum":"forum",
         "publication-forum-type":"type",
         "authors":"auth",
         "keywords":"key1,key2"
      }
   }
```

I tried to access these results through JavaScript.
First I created an array and assigned these results to the array.

The content of the array (named articles) object looks like this;

```
abstract: "xxx"
authors: "yyy"
date: "1111"
keywords: "key1, key2"
paper-id: "abc"
paper-id-type: "xxx"
publication-forum: "yyy"
publication-forum-type: "zzz"
title: "www"
url: "url"
```

Then I tried to access each value in these elements using the format,

```
articles[0]["abstract"]
```

It works for elements that do not have "-" character. So when I tried to extract the paper-id;

```
articles[0]["paper-id"]
```

I'm getting the `error [Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token []`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/62erS/1/)

Comment: On a side note, the object in the question is invalid - it lacks the closing ']' for the array. With that fixed, the original object works for me in Chrome.

Comment: It should works with JSON in the beginning of your question. Seemed, that next action: *First I created an array and assigned these results to the array.* broke your data.

Comment: Your array doesn't look balanced, are you sure that's the full object?

Comment: Thank you kirilloid. You are right. I removed the array and instead of articles[0][paper-id] I tried responseJSON.articles[0]["paper-id"] and it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you forgot to close the `[]` and the `{}` in your JSON

You JSON should look like this

```
{
   "articles":[
      {
         "paper-id":"id",
         "paper-id-type":"type",
         "title":"title",
         "url":"url",
         "abstract":"abs",
         "date":"date",
         "publication-forum":"forum",
         "publication-forum-type":"type",
         "authors":"auth",
         "keywords":"key1,key2"
      }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
abc = {
    "articles": [{
            "paper-id": "id",
            "paper-id-type": "type",
            "title": "title",
            "url": "url",
            "abstract": "abs",
            "date": "date",
            "publication-forum": "forum",
            "publication-forum-type": "type",
            "authors": "auth",
            "keywords": "key1,key2"
        }
    ]
};

for (i in abc['articles'][0]) {
    console.log(abc['articles'][0][i]);
}
```